# Mac OS Sierra System Settings won't stay set

Tags: macos, system-settings

I just got a new 15" MBP with Mac OS Sierra. I've changed the System Preferences to allow me to drag and drop things with the touchpad (under accessibility) and to prevent tap clicking.

But after I leave the system preferences pane, and return to check it out, the preferences have changed. Is this a known issue with Mac OS Sierra? Or did the method of confirming changes, change? I'm at a loss for this one.

Comment: Are the prefs locked? Padlock icon, bottom left. If so, unlock first, then adjust.

Comment: Neither of those are settings that require a password to unlock. And there's no option to unlock the preferences in the corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible your Accessibility preference file is corrupted.

Open **Finder**, then press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>. In the popup textbox, type in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Locate `com.apple.universalaccess.plist` and delete it. Now restart your system.

If the issue persists, you can delete the new preference file, then pull the original file back out of the **Trash** before restarting one more time.